# How to make a search bar in django thag filters the queryset based on what choices are been taken?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a search bar which would filter the queryset based on choices user selects from search bar.But I am failing to make it as I don't know how to do it.

Here's the search bar template

```
<div class="sidebar-left">
                    <!-- Advanced search start -->
                     <!-- Advanced search start -->

                    <form method="get"  action="{% url 'property:search' %}">

                        <h3 class="sidebar-title">Advanced Search</h3>
                        <div class="s-border"></div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="selectpicker search-fields"  name="q1" >
                                    <option>All Status</option>
                                    <option>For Sale</option>
                                    <option>For Rent</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="selectpicker search-fields"  name="q2" >
                                    <option>location</option>
                                    <option>California</option>
                                    <option>American Samoa</option>
                                    <option>Belgium</option>
                                    <option>Canada</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="q3" >
                                            <option>Bedrooms</option>
                                            <option>1</option>
                                            <option>2</option>
                                            <option>3</option>
                                            <option>4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="selectpicker search-fields"  name="q4" >
                                            <option>Bathroom</option>
                                            <option>1</option>
                                            <option>2</option>
                                            <option>3</option>
                                            <option>4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="range-slider">
                                <label>Area</label>
                                <div data-min="0" data-max="10000" data-min-name="min_area" data-max-name="max_area" data-unit="Sq ft" class="range-slider-ui ui-slider" aria-disabled="false" name="q5" ></div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="range-slider">
                                <label>Price</label>
                                <div data-min="0" data-max="150000"  data-min-name="min_price" data-max-name="max_price" data-unit="USD" class="range-slider-ui ui-slider" aria-disabled="false" name="q6" ></div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-0">
                                <input  type="submit" class="search-button">Search</input>
                            </div>

                        </form>

                    <!-- Recent properties start -->
                    <h3 class="sidebar-title">Recent Properties</h3>
                    {% for i in most_recent %}
                    <div class="widget recent-properties">
                        <div class="s-border"></div>
                        <div class="media mb-4">
                            <a class="pr-3" href="properties-details.html">
                                <img class="media-object" src="{{i.images.url}}" alt="small-properties">
                            </a>
                            <div class="media-body align-self-center">
                                <h5>
                                    <a href="#">{{i.title}}</a>
                                </h5>
                                <div class="listing-post-meta">
                                    ${{i.price}} | <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{i.timestamp}} </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <!-- Posts by category Start -->

                    <div class="posts-by-category widget">
                        <h3 class="sidebar-title">Category</h3>
                        <div class="s-border"></div>


                        <ul class="list-unstyled list-cat breadcrumbs">
                            {% for i in category %}
                             <li><a href="{% url 'property:category' i.pk %}" class="nav-link">{{ i.title }}</a><br></li>
                            {% endfor %}            
                        </ul>


                    </div>


                    <!-- Our agent sidebar start -->






                    <!-- Our agent sidebar start -->

                </div>
```

Here's the view for properties and search too

```
   def Properties_List(request):
    category = models.Category.objects.all()

    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = models.Property.objects.order_by('-timpestamp')[:2]
    model = models.Property.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        model = model.filter(

            Q(# WHAT THE HECK SHOULD BE WRTITTEN HERE 
            )


        )


    paginator = Paginator(model,1)
    page_var = 'list'
    page = request.GET.get(page_var)


    try:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)

    index = paginated_queryset.number - 1 
    max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
    start_index = index - 3 if index >= 3 else 0
    end_index = index + 3 if index <= max_index - 3 else max_index
    page_range = list(paginator.page_range)[start_index:end_index]


    context = {
        "property":paginated_queryset,
        'page_var':page_var,
        'page_range':page_range,
        'most_recent':most_recent,
        'category_count':category_count,
        'category': category
        }

    template_name = 'properties/properties_list.html'   
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

The template above as you can see has some options so how to filter these objects based on what actually user choosed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose I have one Product model having `name`, `description` fields

First fetch all the objects and show like this:

```
products= Product.objects.all()
```

Now if you want to filter products based on name and description then you pass something like this in filter. Before that check, if the user has queried

```
if query:
     Product.objects.filter(
                  Q(name__icontains=query)|
                  Q(description__icontains=query)).all()
```